# create a state diagram from xml file

Tags: xml, drawing, state-diagram

I am looking for a free tool to be able to create a state diagram from my simple xml with nodes and edges. What effective tools are out there.

I only know this http://www.cytoscape.org/

and rather to see if anyone have any smooth experience with any other tool?

Comment: You can create a little script in Perl to do that, look at [this](http://search.cpan.org/~lbrocard/GraphViz-2.02/lib/GraphViz/XML.pm)

Answer (score 1):

GraphViz can do this very nicely. There's an XML input language called DotML that can describe a graph, and GraphViz will then render it into SVG. You should find it easy write an XSLT transformation to generate DotML from your "simple XML". Examples of graphs drawn this way can be found in the (superseded) XSLT 2.1 draft specification here:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-xslt-21-20100511/#streamability-choice-and-repetition

(some browsers do a better job than others at rendering the SVG). GraphViz (and DotML) give you a lot of control over how the graph is drawn, but it defaults everything so the minumum you have to give it is just a list of nodes and edges.